# Rest WebService for performing business operation

Tags: web-services, rest

As I've read, Rest is used for create/update/delete/get of Resource using PUT/POST/DELETE/GET method.

Now Let's say, I've to expose a service which take 'price' and 'date' as request and it calculates 'service tax', 'sb cess', 'krishikalyalcess' on 'price' and 'date'. Api doesn't store/upate/delete anything in database/storage. I can easily do it using rest method in controller which takes request and provides desired response, and I can perform calculation of taxes and cess in that method.

My question is - I'll work fine. But does it come under REST as request ('price' and 'date') are neighter resource nor they are doing any CRUD operation in database/storage.

Please help me understand State transfer of Resource and Calling Business oriented method using REST.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading [Richardson Maturity Model](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

> A model (developed by Leonard Richardson) that breaks down the
>   principal elements of a REST approach into three steps. These
>   introduce resources, http verbs, and hypermedia controls.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're intepreting RESTful web services too literal.

Developers expose RESTful web services for a variety of reasons.  Sure, one of the most known is to take the HTTP verbs `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, and `GET` and couple those based on some defined input *resource* to perform a specific action related to the CRUD-paradigm.  But that isn't the only way to interpret a RESTful web service nor does a RESTful service have to interact specifically with some database.

The *resource* in your case is the calculation.  What you are doing is exposing the calculation so that providing a series of inputs allows any external source to obtain a calculated value in a standard, highly accepted pattern.